# Filling a Div with Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a small page that has a div of defined size with all of its content set to not be displayed.

Above the div is a list of p tags that act as "links" to change the content of the div when clicked. However, I just can't seem to get this to work.

**HTML**

```
<p id="link1">Content 1</p>
<p id="link2">Content 2</p>
<p id="link3">Content 3</p>

<div class="subcontent">
<div class="hide cont1">
<p>Title</p>
<p>Content 1</p>
</div>
<div class="hide cont2">
<p>Title</p>
<p>Content 2</p>
</div>
<div class="hide cont3">
<p>Title</p>
<p>Content 3</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.subcontent{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 1px #DDD;
    height:300px;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin-left: 22%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 90%;
}
.hide{
    display: none;
```

Any ideas on what is the best way to get Content 1 to appear if #link1 is clicked?

Also, if content has been displayed with one click, how can I get it back to being hidden before the new content is displayed?

I'm sorry if any of the ideas I've presented aren't clear - I'm still very new to all of this.

Comment: Did you try anything to make it work?

Comment: I tried some several different Javascript and JQuery concepts I came across. Most of them were geared toward replacing content that is already there rather than changing the display property like I want to do, so it didn't get me very far. I tried one method that required me to change the id's and classes on the links and content so that the function would search for the content class that matched the link id and change that content's display property, but it wasn't successful.

Comment: When you ask a question, it will be great if you could share what you have already tried...

Comment: Right- sorry. These are the two techniques I tried: 
1> http://codepen.io/johnmotyljr/pen/qhvue

2> http://codepen.io/JoshBlackwood/pen/yoLBJ

Answer (score 4):

Couple of things:

1) You need to write the click handler for `p` elements.

2) then extract number from clicked element id

3) use extracted number to create selector for targeting desired div

```
 $("p[id^=link]").click(function(){
  var currentdivshowid=this.id.replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
  $('.hide').not(".cont"+currentdivshowid).hide();
  $(".cont"+currentdivshowid).toggle();
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ajf4t3fs/)**

Comment: Well, looking at the Demo, this is a very concise way of doing it, especially since some of the pages I'm using this on have quite a few links. I've tried it, but I'm not getting any results. As embarrassing as it is, I think I might be linking to the external Javascript file incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript (and/or JQuery) you can use the EventHandlers for onclick events. You would associate an event handler for onclick for each of the p tags via their ID's. You would then use the function that is triggered from this event handler to change the display of the associated div.

Try reading up a bit about event handlers. There are ones for onclick, mouseover and many other triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I did the whole thing with vanilla Javascript. I changed a bit of the html handlers. :)

```
<style>
#subcontent{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 1px #DDD;
    height:300px;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin-left: 22%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 90%;
}
.hide{
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="link1">Content 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">Contect 2</a>
<a href="#" id="link3">Contect 3</a>

<div id="subcontent">
    <div id="cont1" class="hide">
        <p>Title</p>
        <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cont2" class="hide">
        <p>Title</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cont3" class="hide">
        <p>Title</p>
        <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

//grab document handles
var link1 = document.getElementById('link1');
var link2 = document.getElementById('link2');
var link3 = document.getElementById('link3');

link1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    showContent('cont1');
});

link2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    showContent('cont2');
});   

link3.addEventListener('click', function(){
    showContent('cont3');
});     

function showContent(idName) {
    var children = document.getElementById('subcontent').childNodes;

    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if(children[i].nodeName == "DIV") {
            children[i].style.display = "none";
        };
    };
    document.getElementById(idName).style.display = "block";
};
</script>
```

Comment: This works very well, thank you. I'm sure all of the other suggestions also work, but I guess that this is just the best for my experience level. Thank you very much, magnet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some JQuery that will do the trick. There is likely a more elegant solution but this will do the job [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9g3jrc8f/)

```
$("#link1").click(function(){
    $(".cont1").removeClass("hide");
    $(".cont2").addClass("hide");
    $(".cont3").addClass("hide");
});
$("#link2").click(function(){
    $(".cont2").removeClass("hide");
    $(".cont1").addClass("hide");
    $(".cont3").addClass("hide");
});
$("#link3").click(function(){
    $(".cont3").removeClass("hide");
    $(".cont2").addClass("hide");
    $(".cont1").addClass("hide");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a little change to your HTML, for event delegation. This will do you good for maintainability if you want to add more DIVs and links in the future.

```
<div id="links">
  <p id="link1">Content 1</p>
  <p id="link2">Content 2</p>
  <p id="link3">Content 3</p>
</div>
```

Here's the script

```
document.getElementById('links').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var index = e.target.id.slice(4);
    var showing = document.querySelector('.subcontent > div:not(.hide)');
    if(showing) {
        showing.classList.add('hide');
    }
    document.querySelector('.subcontent > div.cont' + index).classList.remove('hide');
}, false);
```

Explanation:

1. get the index of link you clicked, retrieve the number from its id
2. find out the showing div, which doesn't have a classname `hide`
3. if there is a div showing, hide it by adding classname `hide`
4. find out the div you are going to show, remove classname `hide`